# Remainder value from $0$ to $9999$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was trying to find how many numbers from $0$ to $9999$ that have the remainder value of $23$. I tried writing a program to help me solve that but it got me nowhere. There has to be a simpler way to solve this problem without writing a program for this.

EDIT: Remainder value of $23$ after division by $100$

Comment: Remainder value of $23$ after division by what?

Comment: @BrianTung After division by 100, sorry I forgot to include that.

Comment: Well, why don't you try listing the first few such numbers?  With division by $100$, it should be fairly simple to write out a few examples and extrapolate a pattern.

Comment: @BrianTung I think I see what you mean, any number that ends with 23 divided by 100 should have a remainder of 23. Is that correct?

Comment: Assuming you mean "should have a remainder of $23$", then yes.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$23 \equiv 23 \pmod{100}$$
$$123 \equiv 23 \pmod{100}$$
$$223 \equiv 23 \pmod{100}$$
$$\vdots$$ 
$$100k + 23 \equiv 23 \pmod{100}$$
($\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, k>0)$

Comment: Thank you for your help, I see the solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Is this question complete "find how many numbers from 0 to 9999 have the remainder value of 23." With what you divide to get 23 ?

Comment: By 100, sorry I forgot to include it.

Comment: Count all the numbers that ends with 23,123,223,323,....1023,1123,1223.... like this.

Comment: Yea I just understood how to solve it. I'm stupid.. Thank you for your help.